# Increase space available for window names in tmux status bar

Tags: tmux

How would I go about increasing the space available for window names in the tmux status bar?

By default it seems to be a single line. I'm hoping there's an option to make the status bar take up several lines, or something to that effect.

Comment: According to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195259/can-byobu-tmux-show-a-multiline-status), it's not very possible to span multiple lines. But a nice tip in there.

Comment: You might just want to use the `choose-window` command (bound to <Prefix>-w by default), to display the list of windows in the current session.  Press `q` to dismiss the list without actually choosing a new window to display.